# Call translation from component.ts in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, internationalization

I'm internationalizing an Angular app by using `@angular/localize`.

The problem is that I have some messages that should be triggered from the `.component.ts` and I don't know how to call a translation in `messages.xlf`.

For example:

With this translation in `messages.pt.xlf`:

```
<trans-unit id="Summary" datatype="html">
    <source>Summary</source>
    <target>Resumo</target>
</trans-unit>
```

I would want to show an alert from typescript.

[The docs](https://angular.io/guide/i18n) says nothing about if it's even possible.

P.S: I know I can create a json with the translation I need to call for typescript or things like that but I'm asking if there is a way to use the same file for the HTML and the Typescript.

Comment: You need to use the `$localize` template string tag. This article explains it pretty well: https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2019/12/10/angular-localize/

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need, thanks.